# fadeIn() value into an input field, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been reading several answers to questions here on SA about how to fade a value into an input field. And when I try the code, it doesn't work. I've tried a couple of things but still no luck:

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bLcszctz/1/

I've tried:

```
$('#workinggeo').click(function () {
    $('.working').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        $('.working').val('finding...');
    });
});
```

and

```
$('#workinggeo').click(function () {
     $('.working').val('finding...').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

with zero luck, can anyone help solve this please, if it's at all possible. Many thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bLcszctz/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides using the animate process described by j08691 you can also use [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

[Browser compatibility chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

```js
$('#workinggeo').click(function () {
    $('.working').val("finding...").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
input.working {
    transition: color 1s;
    color:#FFF;
}
input.show {
    color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="worksearch">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="working">
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="workinggeo">test</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: this is a very clean solution Patrick. Thank you very much for this, works perfectly and with the least amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

First hide then only use fadeIn:

```
$('.working').val('finding...').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLcszctz/2/).

Comment: it's is also hiding the input element.

Comment: Thanks but as @Ashad mentioned the input also fades, which isn't ideal. Would have been a nice, short fix though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind also loading jQuery UI you can animate the rgba color property of the text with:

```
$('#workinggeo').click(function () {
    $('.working').val('finding...').animate({
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
    },1000);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/joooe66x/1)**

Comment: Hi thanks for the input but I really want to avoid UI :-(, I have enough code on my page already, unfortunately. And it just doesn't make sense for me to load the library for one simple animation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other possible solutions, and if you don't want to get into the hassle of having to add jQUery UI or try CSS transitions, you can implement this only with jQuery by playing with the `animation()` function and the `step` function:

```
$('#workinggeo').click(function () {

    if (!this.anim) {
        this.anim = { st:0 };
    }

    $(".working").val("finding...");

    $(this.anim).stop(true, false).animate(
        { st: 100 },
        {
            duration:1000,
            step: function(now, fx) {
                $(".working").css("color", "rgba(0,0,0," + (now/100) + ")");
            }
        }
    );
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/tgt6xtLh/

Comment: this works beautifully. the first one that I've tested that fades in the value beautifully so thanks for that. And without needing to load the UI library is even better. I'll take a look at the other answers but up to now my favorite so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting the modern browsers (and can comfortably use CSS3 features), I'd have a placeholder and use the opacity property to fade in on input focus (and no use of javascript), like this:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
   opacity: 0; 
}
input:-moz-placeholder { 
   opacity: 0;  
}
input::-moz-placeholder { 
   opacity: 0;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { 
   opacity: 0;
}
input[placehodler] {
  opacity: 0;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
   opacity: 1; 
   color: #000;
   transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s ease; 
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { 
   opacity: 1;
   color: #000;
   transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s ease; 
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { 
   opacity: 1;
   color: #000;
   transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s ease; 
}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { 
   opacity: 1;
   color: #000;
   transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s ease; 
}
input[placehodler]:focus {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #000;
  transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s ease; 
}
```

Note that grouping the placeholder CSS does not work on some browsers, so they are placed as single rules.

I have a working jsbin example here[1]

[1] http://jsbin.com/xudizi/3/edit?html,css,output